# Jenkins Pipeline: Using Env Var in another Env Var declaration

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-multibranch

I would like to make my long "ssh" command reusable as a simple variable throughout my pipeline. To do this, it would be nice to declare my hostname in a var, then use that var in another var declaration to build the final command:

```
environment {
    BUILDHOST   = 'buildhost.example.com'
    SSHCMD      = 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no jenkins@${env.BUILDHOST}'
}
```

So conceptually in something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        BUILDHOST   = 'buildhost01.example.com'
        SSHCMD      = 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no jenkins@${env.BUILDHOST}'
    }
    stages {
        stage('SSH Testing') {
            steps {
                sshagent ( ['jenkins_ssh']) {
                    sh '''
                        $SSHCMD uname -a
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Example Test') {
            steps {
                sshagent ( ['jenkins_ssh']) {
                    sh '''
                        $SSHCMD /run/something.sh
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when I declare the var without any substitutions: 

`SSHCMD = 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no jenkins@buildhost.example.com'`

but I can't seem to nest together the variables. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. However, you need to use double-quotes for [String interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        BUILDHOST   = 'buildhost01.example.com'
        SSHCMD      = "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no jenkins@${env.BUILDHOST}" // <<< double-quotes
    }
    stages {
        stage('SSH Testing') {
            steps {
                sshagent ( ['jenkins_ssh']) {
                    sh """ // <<< double-quotes
                        $SSHCMD uname -a
                    """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Example Test') {
            steps {
                sshagent ( ['jenkins_ssh']) {
                    sh """ // <<< double-quotes
                        $SSHCMD /run/something.sh
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39725342/366749).

Comment: Works. I didn't try the exact snippet you showed here because I wanted double quotes around the declaration of SSHCMD since it interpolates the variable (just for safety). Works fine like that so I'm sticking with it. ex... `SSHCMD = "..."` instead of `SSHCMD = '...'`

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot that top one which was your specific ask. I have edited y answer for completeness. Thanks for accepting.